# Design Sizes for Normal, Large, Extra-Large Android Phones and Tablets

Tags: android, css

We have a mobile application using webview and HTML, CSS, jQuery. The application was first developed for Samsung Galaxy Mini as its pilot platform and now it is intended to provide a decent UI in all Android phones and tablets.

The application layout is simple - 1 column, and we do not want to change the design layout -the number of columns. We will create different layouts in photoshop, but what should be the psd sizes to cover normal, large, and extra-large window sizes?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
for best Design :-

```
    xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
    large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
    normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
    small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Comment: Thank you. We're a bit confused about how to use dp in our layout design in photoshop. For Samsung Galaxy Mini, we had a photoshop layout 320px * 511px. Now for "normal" screens, shall we have a 470px * 230px layout minimum? What should be the min width and height in "px" for large screens? We are planning about using media queries with different css files for xlarge, large, normal screens. Would this be suitable to address all Android phones and tablets? Thank you.

Comment: For 960dp x 720dp 
dpi = 320 
px = dp * (dpi / 160) 
hense,

Height = 960dp * (320 / 160) = 1920px

Width = 720dp * (320 / 160) = 1440px

Comment: densities:
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi

Comment: Thank you. So, by combining this information with the Google's Screen Sizes and Densities, which can be found at the following address, we could define the layout widths and heights for Android phones and tablets: https://developer.android.com/intl/in/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens